# Show for a monotonic function $f$ on $(a,b)$ is $\omega_f(x_0)=|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Show for a monotonic function $f$ on $(a,b)$ is $\omega_f(x_0)=|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)|$

---

**My attempt:**

$\forall \delta >0$ we call

$\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$ the oscillation of $f$ in $\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b)$ which means, the

$\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))=\sup f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))-\inf f (\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$

$=\sup\lbrace |f(x)-f(y)||x,y \in \mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b) \rbrace$

The existence of $\sup f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$ and $\inf f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$ is obvious, since

$\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b)=\lbrace x\in (a,b)| x_0-\delta<x<x_0+\delta \rbrace$

and since $f$ is monotonic (lets say w.l.o.g) growing

$f(x_0-\delta)\le f(x) \le f(x_0+\delta)$, $\forall x \in \mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b)$

$\omega_f(x_0):=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$

So finally :

> Given

$\omega_f(x_0):=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\sup\lbrace |f(x)-f(y)||x,y \in \mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b) \rbrace$

> End of given

$=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\left(\left|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0-\delta}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0+\delta}f(x)\right|\right)=|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)|$

Could someone verify my solution, or give critic ? :)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm just not familiar with the specific area, but I'm not sure what the symbols $\Omega_f, U_\delta$ are. Perhaps you should define them here or give context and reference to this problem.

Comment: The main critic is that you're writing a list of equations without justifications. For example, you're not even mentioning that the function is monotonic. It should appear in your proof.

Comment: okey ill update it soon :)

Comment: okey now i updated it :)

Answer (score 2):

You have set this up correctly, but you have not actually proved the final conclusive statement.

If $\delta$ is sufficiently small we have $\bar{U}_\delta(x_0) \subset (a,b)$ -- that is the closed ball of sufficiently small radius is contained in the open interval -- and $f$ is defined on $\bar{U}_\delta(x_0)$.  Thus, for all $x,y \in \bar{U}_\delta(x_0)$ it follows that  $f(x_0-\delta) \leqslant f(x), f(y) \leqslant f(x_0 + \delta)$ and

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant f(x_0+ \delta) - f(x_0-\delta)$$

Whence,

$$\sup_{x,y \in U_\delta(x_0) \cap (a,b)}|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant f(x_0+ \delta) - f(x_0-\delta)$$

Since, $f$ is monotonic we have existence of the limits

$$\lim_{x \searrow x_0}f(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0+}f(x_0 + \delta), \quad\lim_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0+}f(x_0 - \delta)$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)- \lim_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x) \leqslant\\ \liminf_{\delta\to 0+}\sup_{x,y \in U_\delta(x_0) \cap (a,b)}|f(x) - f(y)|\leqslant \limsup_{\delta\to 0+}\sup_{x,y \in U_\delta(x_0) \cap (a,b)}|f(x) - f(y)|\\  \leqslant\lim_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)- \lim_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x) ,$$

which implies that the limit of $\displaystyle \sup_{x,y \in U_\delta(x_0) \cap (a,b)}|f(x) - f(y)|$ as $\delta \to 0+$ exists and

$$\omega_f(x_0) = \lim_{\delta \to 0+}\sup_{x,y \in U_\delta(x_0) \cap (a,b)}|f(x) - f(y)|  \leqslant\lim_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)- \lim_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)$$

Comment: which statement did I not prove? I think the actual problem was that (ill mark which part im referring to) was given in my textbook

Comment: Isnt what I did rewrite a given expression, in a valid manner hence the monotonic behavior was given?

Comment: You wrote a true fact: $\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))=\sup f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))-\inf f (\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))$ and you gave a definition $\omega_f(x_0):=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\Omega_f(\mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b))=\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\sup\lbrace |f(x)-f(y)||x,y \in \mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b) \rbrace$ and then …

Comment: ... you wrote $\omega_f(x_0) =\lim\limits_{\delta \searrow 0}\left(\left|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0-\delta}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0+\delta}f(x)\right|\right)=|\lim\limits_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)|$.  I don't see the justification.  How do you know that limit exists and equals what proceeds it?

Comment: I'm showing that the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of $\sup\lbrace |f(x)-f(y)||x,y \in \mathcal{U}_\delta(x_0)\cap(a,b) \rbrace$ are squeezed between limits both equal to $\lim_{x \searrow x_0}f(x)- \lim_{x \nearrow x_0}f(x)$ to prove this.